# Bad JSON escape sequence: \\1. Path 'sections[0].facts[0].value', line 1, position 196."

Tags: json, .net-core

Am getting getting `Bad JSON escape sequence: \\1. Path 'sections[0].facts[0].value', line 1, position 196."` while parsing json string with `string.Format` to add data based on placeholder.

Below is the code :

```cs
string jsonFormatString = @"{{""title"": ""{0}"",""sections"": [{{""facts"": [{{""name"": ""TransactionNo"",""value"": ""{1}""}}]}}]}}";
string formattedJson= string.Format(jsonFormatString , message, transactionNo ?? "");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(formattedJson);
```

The string values for placeholders were message  = "Transaction Success", transactionNo = "1920\01\ABC";

Looks like escape character **transactionNo** field is creating problem.

I tried with string.Replace(@"\\", @"\") and others nothing helped in resolving the error.

If i added string.Replace(@"\", @"\\", it works but result json contains transactionNo as "1920\\01\\ABC" which is also wrong.

Am i missing something or should i add anything more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen folks do this in the past and even had to maintain code that looks like this... and as you are experiencing: It is a *huge* PITA.

You can easily lay out your objects using `anonymous` types so they are simple to maintain and understand for the folks who may have the pleasure to work with your code in the future.

Take a look at this:

```
var myObj = new {
    title = "<input value>",
    sections = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            facts = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    name = "TransactionNo",
                    value = "<input value>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Result will look like this:

```
{
  "title": "<input value>",
  "sections": [
    {
      "facts": [
        {
          "name": "TransactionNo",
          "value": "<input value>"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, keep in mind that this *is* easier to maintain than formatting a string, but at the end of the day it's better to just bite the bullet and create some concrete models.

Comment: hi @andy

i already tried this anonymous methodology, problem with this is in final response "value": "1920\\01\\ABC" instead of  "1920\01\ABC"

Comment: @A.K -- when you format backslashes to a JSON string, they are "escaped", when you deserialize, they will go back to normal. Play with this to see what I mean: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output

Comment: Thanks !! yah got it !! resolved it using dynamic JObject formation  !